# How can I deal with unwanted numbers in my dataframe where I only want date format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, object, dtype

In my dataframe I have a column called Competencia where only dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD should be. But I just found out that I have a couple of zeros and suddenly and a number like for example 11. Which shouldnt be in it. The Column Competencia has currently the Dtype OBJECT. I normally created a new column called dt_COMP and converted all the dates into datetime which is the format I need. Now my question is, what do I do with the unwanted 0's and the 11 and how do I do it?

If I try to run my code ignoring the 0's and 11 I get the error which I dont understand:

`ParserError: Unknown string format: COMPETENCIA`

This is the Code that I use to convert COMPETENCIA into Datetime in a new column called dt_COMP

```
#Converting 'COMPETENCIA' into date -> new Column: 'dt_COMP'

df30_new['dt_COMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df30_new['COMPETENCIA'], yearfirst=True)

df30_new['dt_COMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df30_new['dt_COMP']).dt.date
df30_new["dt_COMP"] = pd.to_datetime(df30_new["COMPETENCIA"], format="%Y/%m/%d")
```

in the screenshot you can see the zeros and the 11
[image]

Comment: you're updating the same dt_COMP column three times. Why?  secondly, provide a reproducible example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You could set keyword "errors" to "coerce" which would give you Not-A-Time values (`NaT`) where a string could not be converted; `pd.to_datetime(df30_new['COMPETENCIA'], yearfirst=True, errors="coerce")`

Comment: @FObersteiner Thank you! thats exactlz what I did and it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this if I remember rightly - doing from memory

`df30_new['COMPETENCIA_TRIMMED'] = df30_new['COMPETENCIA'].apply(lambda x: x if type(x) is datetime else None, axis=1)`

Maybe check the datatype of one of the correct values for this to work as expected.

Check out apply in the pandas docs.

Comment: I like this idea, but type(x) is datetime wouldnt work because type is object at current state. So I must filter it at like YYYY-MM-DD only structured objects, any idea ?

Comment: the column is dtype is object but each individual element might be INT or STR or DATETIME etc I believe.

Comment: if you do `type(df.loc[row, column_name])` on a valid date you will find the true data type.